# String measurement with Graphics.MeasureString

Tags: c#, graphics, measurement

Please see my code:

```
Graphics grfx = Graphics.FromImage(new Bitmap(1, 1));

System.Drawing.Font f = new System.Drawing.Font("Times New Roman", 10, FontStyle.Regular);

const string text1 = "check_space";
SizeF bounds1 = grfx.MeasureString(text1, f);

const string text2 = "check_space ";
SizeF bounds2 = grfx.MeasureString(text2, f);

Assert.IsTrue(bounds1.Width < bounds2.Width); // I have Fail here!
```

I wonder why my test is failed. Why text **with** space in tail is **NOT** greater by width than text **without** space?

**UPDATE:** I can understand these both strings are not equal. But as I mentally understand the string **with** space should be greater by width than the string **without** space. Don't?

Comment: Are they equal by any chance?

Comment: Try with `"check_space."` and `"check_space ."`. They are not equal.

Comment: I already posted the answer below. I'm not sure why you haven't accepted it...

Comment: Because it has to pass some time - the system do not permit accept it immediately

Answer (score 15, accepted):

you have to tell it to measure trailing spaces, which it does not by default.

```
Graphics grfx = Graphics.FromImage(new Bitmap(1, 1));

System.Drawing.Font f = new System.Drawing.Font("Times New Roman", 10, FontStyle.Regular);

string text1 = "check_space";
SizeF bounds1 = grfx.MeasureString(text1, f, new PointF(0,0), new StringFormat( StringFormatFlags.MeasureTrailingSpaces ));

string text2 = "check_space ";
SizeF bounds2 = grfx.MeasureString(text2, f, new PointF(0,0), new StringFormat( StringFormatFlags.MeasureTrailingSpaces ) );
```

Comment: Wow! Thaks! I have never heard about this